# Joint distribution of the magnitude/phase of a circular bivariate normal distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution

A bivariate normal distribution with no correlation and identical variance in both dimensions can be written as
$$
P(x,y|\mu_x, \mu_y, \sigma) = \frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2}\exp{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu_x}{\sigma}\right)^2 -\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{y-\mu_y}{\sigma}\right)^2\right)}
$$
I'm interested in corresponding distributions for the magnitude $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and phase $\phi = \mathrm{arctan}(y/x)$.

I believe the marginal distribution for the magnitude is given by the [Rice distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice_distribution), **but I'm looking for the joint distribution $P(r, \phi|...)$ or the marginal phase distribution $P( \phi|...)$**.

I did find [this reference](http://iranarze.ir/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/E2067.pdf), which gives expressions for the completely general case of a bivariate normal distribution, but I suspect simpler results exist for this special case.

Anyone happen to know what they are?

Thanks!

Comment: Just apply the results in your reference for the bivariate normal distribution.  The simplification is that $b-a=2\gamma=0, $ which makes all the $\cos(2\theta)$ terms disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplifying the results from the reference given in the question, the joint distribution of $r$ and $\phi$ is given by
\begin{equation}
P(r,\phi|\mu_x, \mu_y, \sigma) = \frac{r}{2\pi\sigma^2} \exp{\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \left(r^2 -2r(\mu_x \cos{\phi} +\mu_y \sin{\phi}) + \mu_x^2 + \mu_y^2\right) \right)}
\end{equation}
We can re-express the above in terms of the central magnitude $r_0 = \sqrt{\mu_x^2 + \mu_y^2}$ and and central phase $\phi_0 = \mathrm{arctan}(\mu_y/\mu_x)$ to give
\begin{align*}
P(r,\phi|r_0, \phi_0, \sigma) &= \frac{r}{2\pi\sigma^2} \exp{\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \left(r^2 + r_0^2 -2r r_0(\cos{\phi_0} \cos{\phi} +\sin{\phi_0} \sin{\phi})\right) \right)} \\
&= \frac{r}{2\pi\sigma^2} \exp{\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \left(r^2 + r_0^2 -2r r_0 \cos{(\phi-\phi_0)} \right) \right)}
\end{align*}